# Interection of conjugate elements forms a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be its subgroup. Then, is the set $W=\cap_{g\in G} gHg^{-1}$ a normal subgroup?

I think the answer is yes, because the set is equal to the stabilizer of the action of $H$ on $G$ with action as conjugation, which is the normalizer of $H$. Any ideas. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Yes I think you can think of it that way, but an inspection on the inclusion should also reveal the same information. That is if we just write out $gWg^{-1} ? \in  W$ (\stackrel doesn't work here...)